# Is free product of groups always bigger that direct product?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product, free-product

My question is as follow:

Let $\{G_\alpha\}, \alpha \in A$ be a class of groups. Is it always true that there exists a surjective homomorphism $\phi$
$$\phi:*_\alpha \,G_\alpha\, \to \prod_\alpha G_\alpha.\,$$

For example, there is a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

And how to type the * bigger?

Comment: Ok. Consider now the situation in which all the groups are nontrivial and there are countably many groups: what Cardinals do the direct product and free product have?

Comment: Ok. I understand. So if I change direct product to direct sum, then the statement is correct.

Comment: Indeed, that works.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Can you have a surjective homomorphism from
$$
 \underset{{i\in\mathbb{N}}}{{\LARGE{\ast}}}\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}_2 ?
$$What would be the image of $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)   $?

Comment: The photo cannot be easily searched and may not always be available to users in other countries. Typing your suggestion out would improve the quality of your answer significantly.

Comment: Ok I will improve

Comment: Isn't $(1,1,\cdots)$ an element of the direct product, not the free product?

Comment: Sorry I mean the preimage

Comment: And as an aside, even if posting an image were appropriate on mse, it should be cropped to the relevant content rather than being mostly empty space.